# How to solve unexpected errors from a CSS selector

Tags: html, css, sass

I am learning SASS. I am trying to make a webpage using SASS. There is some error showing in the CSS file generated from the SASS file.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.links {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[5];
      grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px -1px #6b6666;
          box-shadow: 0 -1px 3px -1px #6b6666;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
}
```

Image of the code:

[image]

Why those errors are showing?

How can I fix the errors?

Comment: What is validating it? Code editor or an external extension? Is the file saved in the correct format?

Comment: Code editor is validating it. I am using VScode and `live sass compiler` extension.

Comment: The fact you have a CSS file to look at at all means your Sass is fine. My guess is that whatever is highlighting your CSS file isn't familiar with the `-ms-grid-columns` syntax, since the errors start at the `[5]`

Comment: Okay, where is the SASS code? I just deleted the `-ms-grid-columns` line from the CSS and the errors went away: https://nimb.ws/F5dPIl That property with the 's' is not even supported: https://nimb.ws/AvotLr So just check with the SASS compiler version. It might be old or the configuration would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

before:-
-ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[5];

after:-
-ms-grid-columns: (5,1fr); or -ms-grid-columns: (1fr,5);